# object reference not set to an instance of an object error for timer1 when I press refresh

Tags: vb.net

I am getting this error with my source code when I press refresh button to reload the items in the listbox(name filesList).

> NullReferenceException was handled error
>   object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  'selected item is filepath
  Dim filePath = FilesList.SelectedItem.ToString  ' <-- here
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Did you not see the preview before you posted?

Comment: Of course, SelectedItem is Nothing after the refresh and you don't check for this

Comment: Did you checked if `FilesList`or `FilesList.SelectedItem` is `null`? This would explain your error.